# Why am I getting "No module named 'flask.ext'" with Flask-Autodoc?

Tags: python, flask, python-import

In `setup.py` I require both Flask and Flask-Autodoc. I run `setup.py install` and confirm that both distributions are installed.

Following the [directions](https://github.com/acoomans/flask-autodoc), I imported Flask-Autodoc:

```
from flask.ext.autodoc import Autodoc
```

But I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask.ext'`. I'm in a Conda Python 3.6 environment, and the same thing happens when I created a new virtual environment and re-install the package with dependencies.

I thought that Flask extensions are supposed to be imported from the `flask.ext` module, but that doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried the following: `from flask.autodoc import Autodoc`, `from autodoc import Autodoc`, `from FlaskAutodoc import Autodoc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import flask.ext.whatever` is no longer supported in Flask 1.0. Flask-Autodoc's docs [need to be updated](https://github.com/acoomans/flask-autodoc/pull/38). `flask_autodoc` should be imported directly:

```
from flask_autodoc import Autodoc
```

Comment: This is acctually also giving an error. The thing that worked for me was this package: https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Selfdoc/